# How to create slick projection for list of nested case class?

Tags: scala, slick

I am using **play 2.6.6** , **scala 2.12.3** and **slick 3.0.0**.

I had following case class structure initially where there was a nested case class:

```
case class Device(id: Int, deviceUser: Option[DeviceUser] =None)

case class DeviceUser(name: Option[String] = None)
```

So, I had created following projection for **Device class**:

```
class DevicesTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Device](tag, "DEVICES") {

    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)

    def name = column[Option[String]]("NAME")

    def deviceUser = name.<>[Option[DeviceUser]](
      {
        (param: Option[String]) => {
          param match {
            case Some(name) => Some(DeviceUser(Some(name)))
            case None => None
          }
        }
      },
      {
        (t: Option[DeviceUser]) =>
         {
           t match {
             case Some(user) => Some(user.name)
             case None => None
           }
         }
      }
    )

    def * = (id, deviceUser).<>(Device.tupled, Device.unapply)
  }
```

The above setup was working fine. I could easily store and retrieve data using the above projection. `But now, my requirement has changed and I need to store list of nested case class`. So, the class structure is now as follow :

```
case class Device(id: Int, deviceUser: Option[List[DeviceUser]] =None)

case class DeviceUser(name: Option[String] = None)
```

Is there some way where I could define projection for the field **deviceUser: Option[List[DeviceUser]]** ?

**Update** : I am looking for more of a `non-relational` approach here.

Comment: One Device can contain many DeviceUser - so you should represent it as one-to-many relation on DB level

Comment: Yes, that would be a relational way to do. But, I am looking for a more of a `non-relational` approach here.

Comment: Serialize it to JSON/XML and save it in a BLOB column. Your DAL should parse it and create needed types.

Comment: Thats a cool idea but, I would still want data to make some sense in the DB

Comment: But to make it sense at the DB level shouldn't it be relational? Maybe you can go with NoSQL, like MongoDB, but as far as I know, there is not support for MongoDB in Slick. If you need a one-to-many relation example for Slick, I can provide.

Comment: Well,if you see my earlier scenario in the question,it's one to one right.But was it relational approach?No. Was data making sense in the DB?Yes. So I am looking for similar approach where I could still pass `List[DeviceUser]` directly inside `DevicesTable`,and then maybe map the list into individual fields,(may be point to separate table, insert multiple records from there). And when I query, I should get back the list, right from the *projection level*.I don't want to use NoSQL and neither plain relational approach,Somewhere in between, where `DevicesTable(projection)` does heavylifting.

Answer (score 0):

Since, no body has suggested a solution so far, I am sharing the approach that I am using right now. It works but of course is not the best solution.  Specially, I want to avoid using `Await` here and would like to develop a `generic implicit parser`.

ALso, I had to create a separate `DeviceUsersTable`.

```
    case class DeviceUser(id: Int,name: Option[String] = None)

    class DeviceUserRepo @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)  {

      val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
      val db = dbConfig.db
      import dbConfig.profile.api._
      val DeviceUsers = TableQuery[DeviceUserTable]

      private def _findById(id: Int): DBIO[Option[DeviceUser]] =
        DeviceUsers.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption

      def findById(id: Int): Future[Option[DeviceUser]] =
        db.run(_findById(id))

      def all: Future[List[DeviceUser]] =
        db.run(DeviceUsers.to[List].result)

      def create(deviceUser: DeviceUser): Future[Int] = {
        db.run(DeviceUsers returning DeviceUsers.map(_.id) += deviceUser)
      }

      class DeviceUserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[DeviceUser](tag, "DEVICE_USERS") {

        def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
        def name = column[Option[String]]("NAME")
        def * = (id, name).<>(DeviceUser.tupled, DeviceUser.unapply)
      }

    }
```

And the original `DevicesTable` now looks like this :

```
class DevicesTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Device](tag, "DEVICES") {

    implicit val deviceUserConverter = MappedColumnType.base[Option[List[DeviceUser]], String](
      deviceUsersOpt => {
        deviceUsersOpt match {
          case Some(users:List[DeviceUser]) =>val listOfId = users.map{
            k => val res = deviceUserRepo.create(k)
              Await.result(res, 10 seconds)
          }
            listOfId.mkString(",")
          case None => ""
        }
      },
      str =>{
        val listOfIds = (str split "," map Integer.parseInt).toList.filterNot(k => k.equals(""))
        if(listOfIds.nonEmpty){
          val users = listOfIds.map{ k =>
            val res = deviceUserRepo.findById(k)
            Await.result(res, 10 seconds)
          }
          Some(users.flatten)
        } else {
          None
        }
      }
    )

    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)

    def deviceUser = column[Option[List[DeviceUser]]]("DEVICE_USERS")

    def * = (id, deviceUser).<>(Device.tupled, Device.unapply)
  }
```